# Pass a resource object to PHP from Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to pass an imap_conection (PHP Imap Library) using Jquery.  Post doesn't seem to work - is there something else I should try?

**PHP**

```
$connection = imap_open($mailServer,$login,$password);
```

**jQuery**

```
    var dataString='email=<?php echo $email_address; ?>&connection=<?php echo $connection; ?>&password=<?php echo $password; ?>&server=<?php echo $server;?>&daysago='+daysago+'&num='+num;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
```

Right now, Firebug's telling me the $_POST['connection'] variable is `Resource id #57`

Edited to add

**Main Issue**

I am connecting to imap email addresses using the PHP Imap Library. When I try to reconnect multiple times with the ajax (doing multiple keyword searches), I tend to lose connections to certain email providers (mainly Hotmail), so I'm trying to centralize one connection so I don't lose connections - which is why I'd like 1 connection resource and to pass the connection. Is there another possible solution

The reason I use multiple ajax calls/imap connections is that I want to make the data available to users as fast as possible.  This searches usually take about 8-10 seconds each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$connection` is of a special php "type" called a *resource*. These are created by functions like `mysql_connect`, `fopen` and `imap_open` and represent some kind of state in an underlying C library. These resources are *only* valid for the duration of the page execution. As soon as PHP has finished executing the page the resource is released. That's the first part of the problem.

The second part is that when you print a resource it is converted to a string. This string representation has lost the underlying state of the resource, and cannot be converted back to the resource. Thus there's no way of doing what you're trying to do.

**What you need to do is to reestablish the connection to the imap server in search.php, and drop the connection parameter from the ajax call.**

Comment: Thanks for this.  I really need to pass the resource because certain email clients (namely Hotmail) tend to drop my connection after a few connects (probably 6 or 7) when I connect every time using ajax.

Comment: @Bob, Doesn't matter. Even if you use ajax it will reconnect everytime.

Comment: What about fsocketopen() to use a persistent connection?  I just found this post & it seems to be the same problem that I'm having... http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=257822.0

Comment: @Bob: pfsockopen might work. You'll have to replace the built-in imap library with something written in PHP, though. I'm guessing that such implementations exists, and some might even support pfsockopen() natively. Otherwise it should be rather easy to make the modification.

Comment: Thanks - I'm thinking instead of redoing the entire application for hotmail, I'll just not have it in real time & email users results in 10 minutes instead.  Not ideal, but better than a system overhaul.  Appreciate the insights.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you shouldn't include `&connection=<?php echo $connection ;?>` to your URL, because it's a resource, and when you try to echo it into the javascript, it gets converted to a string: `Resource id #57`. You can't pass a PHP resource using JavaScript.

Comment: Is there any solution to sending this resource to a different php page for ajax?

Comment: No, you can only pass these resources within PHP. If you try to pass it to JavaScript, then PHP converts it to a string. What would you like to accomplish exactly? Maybe I could help you more if you'd put me in picture.

Comment: Connecting to imap email addresses using the PHP Imap Library.  When I try to reconnect multiple times with the ajax (doing multiple keyword searches), I tend to lose connections to certain email providers (mainly Hotmail), so I'm trying to centralize one connection so I don't lose connections - which is why I'd like 1 connection resource and to pass the connection.  Is there another possible solution?

Comment: Even if you could be able to pass the resource using Javascript, it would not work, because PHP is not running continously. It gets executed when you make your HTTP request, connects to the mail server, does some work with it, and then stops execution, which means that your `$connection` resource is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 main problems here:

1. When you're trying to echo the resource object, you're calling its `__toString()` method. This will usually print a very generic description of the object, as you've seen here. The proper way to convert an object for passing elsewhere is using the `serialize()` function. [See the docs for it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).
2. Even if you did try serializing it, it would fail. Resource objects are very state-dependent, and thus cannot be passed like this. It can be used in the script that opened it, and that's about it. See the doc above for more info.

As an added bonus:

You're not escaping any of the values in your `dataString`, which could easily lead to values being misinterpreted if there were a `?` or `&` in it. You should either run `escape` on each value being formed, or do something like this:

```
var data = {
  username: '<?php echo $username ?>',
  password: '<?php echo $password ?>'
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "search.php",
  data: data,
  ...
});
```

jQuery will take the object and form the data string for you, and do the proper escaping. Much easier to read, easier to put together, and less easy to make a mistake.

Comment: What are my other options?  Would it be possible to store this object somewhere to transfer it to a different php file?